# Is it possible to connect to third party websocket using azure functions?.How to connect from azure functions to locally installed kafka?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying azure functions to connect to websocket to get the data and send to locally installed kafka in my laptop. but unable to send to kafka?.Is there any way to send data from azure functions to locally installed kafka?

Comment: Do you want your function to be triggered from Kafka, or just send the output data to Kafka, or both?

Comment: is the kakfa input endpoint on ur local machine exposed to the internet ?.

Comment: @Mikhail, I just need to send output data to Kafka

Comment: @Aravind, Could you please guide me how to expose kafka endpoint to internet?.Thanks

Comment: @Dhinesh same as any api on your machine. i believe it will http://localhost and some port . in your firewall you need to open up inbound traffic for that and then try accessing it via public ip address of ur machine. but this kafka i believe will be hosted somewhere in cloud right. i suggest you try that route. why having in local machine ..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Azure Function that will do that for you, so you need to send your messages to Kafka the same you would do from any other .NET code.

The steps:

1. Make sure Kafka is accessible from the internet as @Dhinesh suggested.
2. Pick a Kafka client library to use (the official one is [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet), but there are others too).
3. Write a simple console app which would send some sample messages to your Kafka and make sure it works.
4. Use exactly the same code inside your Azure Function body to send real messages to Kafka.

If you need something more elaborate than this basic guide, feel free to adjust your question.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AppService supports Virtual Networks (vNets). Functions run on top of an AppService so this means that your Functions can securely access your on-prem Kafka instance over VPN. For this to work you would need to:

1. Create a site to site or a site to point VPN using the VNET integration -instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create
2. Ensure your function and app service is inside this vNET - instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

I hope this helps